# Visual Studio C# .dll vs. project referencing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two C# projects in my Visual Studio solution. Project B needs to reference code in Project A. Both projects need to be compiled to dll's and then used in an application.

In Project B I can set a reference to project A and that allows things to compile. But when I actually use the resulting dll's in my application it throws  a missing assembly reference error.

My current solution is to tell Project B to reference the bin/debug/ProjectA.dll. Everything works when running the application with this configuration. But this solution has a number of problems. For instance, any code written in Project A that B relies on wont be visible to B until A has been rebuilt. And building the solution relies on A being built first.

Is there a way that I can add a reference to Project A but have the resulting dll built so it looks for the ProjectA.dll reference and not the project itself? I expect there is, but my google searching has resulted in no answers.

Comment: Can you post the error? Also try rebuilding the project and then run the (I'm assuming) .exe file in the bin folder. If it runs no problem then there is an issue with where you are running it outside of the folder, if there is in an exception when running it in the bin folder then I really need to see the exception and probably some source code to answer more fully

Comment: In Project B right click in the Project A reference and put "Copy Local" = True

Comment: So this problem seems to have resolved it's self. It was a problem before I wen't to work. And then when I got back it was not happening anymore. I have no idea why. What does one do with a post when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, any code written in Project A that B relies on wont be visible to B until A has been rebuilt. And building the solution relies on A being built first.

This is not a problem, this is, in my view, a benefit. As you are guaranteed to not be able access functionality which is not there. In case of a new functionality, one may say, it's not a big deal: I can not find it, got an exception/error so I know something went wrong. But what about *updated* code ? In this way you are guaranteed that `B` will use only most updated version of `A`.

> Is there a way that I can add a reference to ProjectA but have the resulting dll built so it looks for the ProjectA.dll reference and not the project itself?

You may simply implement post-build event on your project `A` which copies it and all dependent DLLs in some predefined central location, where `B.dll` will be copied too. If your `B.dll` depends on `A.dll`, OS, following default behavior, will search for `A.dll` in the same folder where `B.dll` is, for first, before checking %PATH% variable content.